# Problem with inserting a timer in a wordpad

Tags: python, tkinter

I was making a word pad in python with tkinter. I was able to insert a word counter but the timer is the main issue. Every time I use while loop the program finishes it first then opens the window (even with `time.sleep()`) and I want it to show the time decreasing in real time. Thank you in advance and here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
root.title("Word Pad")

entry = Text(root, font=("Times New Roman", 20))
entry.pack()
lab = Label(root)
lab.pack()


def update():
    b = entry.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    count = b.split()
    c = len(count)
    lab.config(text=c)
    root.after(100, update)


lab1 = Label(root, text="--")
lab1.pack()


def clock():
    sec = 30
    while sec > 0:
        sec = sec - 1
        lab1.config(text=sec)


clock()
update()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to use `.after()` instead of a while loop with sleep, like for the word counter.

Comment: I added `root.after(1000, clock)` just below `lab.config(tesxt=sec)` and now the program is not responding :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how you can use `.after()` to replace the while loop in `clock()`:

```
sec = 30

def clock():
    global sec
    if sec > 0:
        sec -= 1
        lab1.config(text=sec)
        root.after(1000, clock)
```

The function decrements the global variable `sec`, update the label and then schedule the next execution of `clock` 1000 ms later.

Comment: Now it works completely fine. I have a query...why `global sec` works but not `sec = 30` ?

Comment: @NishchayRaj if you do `sec = 30` then each `clock()` is executed, `sec` will be equal to 30, while you want a countdown, so `sec` needs to be a global variable, not a local variable inside `clock`